# Backup script for Unix

Tags: tar

I have written a shell script to take backup.

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME=`date +%b-%d-%y`           
FILENAME=backup-$TIME.tar.gz    
SRCDIR=/home/ubuntulover/scripts                 
DESDIR=/home/ubuntulover/Backupfolder        
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR
```

it is executing correctly, but i see tar:

```
Removing leading `/' from member names in terminal, How to remove this.
```

Answer (score 2):

The message is harmless, but if you really want to get rid of it, specify a relative path for `tar` to archive, instead of an absolute one:

```
cd "$SRCDIR"
tar -cpzf "$DESDIR/$FILENAME" .
```

Or:

```
cd /home/ubuntulover/
tar -cpzf "$DESDIR/$FILENAME" scripts
```

Comment: Thanks muru,cd /home/ubuntulover/
tar -cpzf "$DESDIR/$FILENAME" scripts